# C# Paste text gets through validation

Tags: c#, regex, validation, events, textbox

I need to validate simple textbox to prevent the user from entering any special character ("!@#$%* \t"). It works, but the user can bypass this validation by pasting in the value into the textbox by right clicking and pasting. Is there a way to validate the pasted value as well ?

```
 private void NoSpecialCharacter(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        var regex = new Regex(@"[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]");
        if (regex.IsMatch(e.KeyChar.ToString()))
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: is there another event you can tap into like TextChanged or similar?

Comment: With other events the regex won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `TextChanged` Event of `TextBox` control - it works when you put any value in `TextBox`- paste or entered - does not matter.

Make your validation as function with bool result and check it on every `TextChanged` event like this

```
private void textBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (CheckStrng(textBox.Text))
        // Validated - do what you needed
    else
        // Not Validated 
}
```

Instead this LINQ you can make your own method with regex

```
private bool CheckStrng(string str)
    {
     return str.Length == str.Count(x => Char.IsLetterOrDigit(x)) + str.Count(x => Char.IsWhiteSpace(x));
    }
```